# invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError) on lion, # encoding: utf-8 does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest

I am trying to install autotest with growl and fsevent on my mac, but got the following message as many others have got:
    loading autotest/rails_rspec2
    /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/lib/autotest.rb:316:in `load': /Users/xunx/projects/ourbull/.autotest:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/lib/autotest.rb:316:in`block in initialize'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/lib/autotest.rb:315:in `each'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/lib/autotest.rb:315:in`initialize'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/autotest/rspec2.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/autotest/rails_rspec2.rb:31:in`initialize'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/lib/autotest.rb:245:in `new'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/lib/autotest.rb:245:in`run'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/ZenTest-4.6.2/bin/autotest:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/bin/autotest:19:in`load'
    from /Users/xunx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/bin/autotest:19:in `'

I googled around and tried putting # encoding: utf-8 to all these files, but does not work.
Also tried to change the textmate_ruby file as suggested on rvm site, does not work either.

Here is my system:
Mac OS X Lion
Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.0.1
  # gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
  # gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.2'
  # gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.4'
  # gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.9'

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce/blob/master/Gemfile

I had to change Zentest to force 4.5.0

```
gem "ZenTest", '4.5.0'# 4.6 breaks autotest
```